# How to insert and element before another in a linked list

Tags: java, list, linked-list, singly-linked-list

```
public void insertElementBefore(E element, E newElement) {
    MyNode<E> current = head;
    if (head != null) {
        while (current != null) {
            if (current.data.equals(element)) {
                MyNode<E> n = new MyNode<E>(newElement);
                n.next = current.next;
                current.next = n;
                return;
            }
            current = current.next;
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I have for this. I'm having troubles to insert the newElement before intended element. Can't seem to figure out the syntax for it. I've been tinkering with it for a while and the best I could get was for it to insert after the element like it currently does

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of a single linked list, you will need **two** temporary nodes:

- `MyNode<E> current` that will represent the current node in the single linked list.
- `MyNode<E> prev` that will represent a node before the current node in the single linked list.

Then, you have to add the new node between these nodes. If you don't have the `prev` node, then when setting the `current` node as the next node of the new node, then all the nodes before `current` will be lost.

This is how your code would look like:

```
public void insertElementBefore(E element, E newElement) {
    MyNode<E> current = head;
    //check here
    MyNode<E> prev = null;
    if (head != null) {
        while (current != null) {
            if (current.data.equals(element)) {
                MyNode<E> n = new MyNode<E>(newElement);
                n.next = current;
                //check here
                if (prev != null) {
                    prev.next = n;
                }
                return;
            }
            //check here
            prev = current;
            current = current.next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ah, ok. I had two temporary nodes kind of like that before. It was trailCurrent so I kind of had the right idea before I abandoned that.

I'm using yours and now its cutting off any data that would have came after the element was inserted. 
Trying to fix that now

Comment: Alright, I fixed it up. Thanks for all the help. I understand what I was doing wrong now :)

Comment: You're welcome. Please don't forget to mark the post that helped you most as the answer by clicking on the check below the points.

Comment: You don't need the `if (head !- null)` check as that's what you're doing the first time round the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to memorise the previous node.

```
    MyNode<E> current = head;
    MyNode<E> previous = null;
    while (current != null && !current.data.equals(element)) {
            return;
        }
        previous = current;
        current = current.next;
    }
    MyNode<E> n = new MyNode<>(newElement);
    n.next = current;
    if (previous == null) {
       head = n;
    } else {
       previous.next = n;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void Insert_Before(int num)
{
    Node *x=new Node();
    x->data=num;

    if (head==NULL) {
        x->next=head;
        head=x;
    } else {
        int c=1;
        cout<<"Element before which insertion has to take place:";
        cin>>n;
        Node *temp=head;
        Node *temp1;

        //check whether the element is present or not
        while (temp->data!=n) { //if present
            temp=temp->next;
            c=c+1; //finds the position of the element n
        }

        x->next=temp;

        if (c==1) {
            head=x;
        } else {
            int i=1;
            while (i<=c-1) { 
                temp1=temp1->next;
                i=i+1;
            }
            temp1->next=x; 
        }
    }
} //Insert_Before
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Node n=headNode;
    Node prev=null;
    while(n!=null){
        if(n.getData()==node){
            Node newNode=new Node(data);
            prev.setNext(newNode);
            newNode.setNext(n);
            break;
        }
        else{
            prev=n;
            n=n.getNext();
        }
    }
    if(n.getNext()==null){
        Node newNode= new Node(data);
        prev.setNext(newNode);
        newNode.setNext(null);

    }
    System.out.println("New LinkedList after insert before is:");
    printList();
}
```

Create a new  node called previous-node, and keep track of current element. In my code, if the current element matches the value of the node variable, we add a new node before it.