# Insert an element before the specified element in the linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, time-complexity

How to insert an element before the specified element in the linked list, so that the time complexity is n.
For example 
I want to insert 100 before 7

```java
LinkedList<Integer> linkedList = new LinkedList<>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    linkedList.add(i);
}
```

I can do it like this

```java
int index = linkedList.indexOf(7);
if (-1 != index) {
    linkedList.add(index, 100);
}
```

But I have traversed the linked  list twice by this way.
Actually we can do this just by traversing one time.
So how can I do that?
PS：just use LinkedList

Comment: Do you need it in complexity O(n), or must it strictly be a single iteration over the list? Also, are you free to implement your own linked list or must you use Java's implementation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert and element before another in a linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26365140/how-to-insert-and-element-before-another-in-a-linked-list)

Comment: @umop apisdn  Sorry, I didn't describe it clearly. I mean that I want to know how to do it under strictly a single iteration by just using Linkedlist in java. I know we can write an own class to do that. But as a typical linked list class ,can we just use linkedlist?

Comment: No that is not a valid dup link.  It is talking about a *custom* linked list class.  This question is about `LinkedList`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to do this **in one pass** using a `ListIterator`.  A `ListIterator` is like a regular `Iterator` except that you can change the direction of iteration, and you can `add` an element at the current position; see [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html).

So the code goes something like this:

```
    LinkedList<SomeType> list = ...
    SomeType a, b = ..

    // Insert 'b' before the first element equal to 'a' in 'list'
    ListIterator<SomeType> iterator = list.listIterator(0);
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        SomeType e = iterator.next();
        if (e.equals(a)) {
            iterator.previous();  // returns 'e' again.  But the real purpose
                                  // is to reset the iteration position
                                  // so that 'next()' would return 'e' again.
            iterator.add(b);      // inserts before 'next()'.
            break;
        }
    }
```

The `ListIterator::add` operation is an "optional" operation, but it is supported by `LinkedList`.  The `LinkedList` [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#listIterator-int-) say that the above won't cause a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
LinkedList<Integer> linkedList = new LinkedList<>();
int addNumber = 100, beforeTheNumber = 7;
for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    if(i == beforeTheNumber)
        linkedList.add(addNumber);
    linkedList.add(i);
}
```

`linkedList`'s elments should now read: `1,2,3,4,5,6,100,7,8,9,10`.

**Edit:** If you want to insert some value in an already existing `LinkedList`:

```
linkedList.add((linkedList.indexOf(beforeTheNumber) >= 0 ? linkedList.indexOf(beforeTheNumber) : linkedList.size()), addNumber);
```

This code assumes that:

1. `linkedList` exists and is a `LinkedList<Integer>`.
2. `beforeTheNumber` and `addNumber` exist and are integers.

If `linkedList` does not have `beforeTheNumber`, `addNumber` will be added to the end instead.

Comment: Thanks your answer. By this way we can traverse just once. But if there is a given linkedlist, we need another list to copy to Implement insertion。So there isn't a simple way to insert an element like typical C linked list in Linkedlist?

Comment: The `java.util` package has a number of types similar to `LinkedList`. Each one is used for different purposes and has a different set of methods. See the [official Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/index.html) for more information. For example, the `ArrayList` type has a method `add(int i, E e)` that lets you add an element `e` at index `i`. `ArrayList` also has a method called `indexOf(Object o)`  which gets the index of the first occurrence of `o`.

Comment: @Cole Petersen, it is exactly what author proposed by himself.

Comment: @xja The answer has been updated with an example of how to do this with a `LinkedList`. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: @Cole This new answer will still traverse the linked list twice. The following Stephen C's answer perfectly solves this problem.

Comment: As there is two call to indexOf, it can even traverse the list three times in worst case.